# Deleted URLS.py file in Django, how do i reload it

Tags: python, django

I happened to delete my URLS.PY file in my Django project by mistake although URLS are still resolving. How can I recreate the file from the URLS.pyc?

Comment: You can decompile `urls.pyc`, but if your file wasn't that complex, something like `strings urls.pyc` might be easier.

Comment: If you're using version control such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) you should be able to get it back without the `pyc`. If not, I humbly suggest that you take this experience as an indication that you should use it in future. For everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if using python 2.7:

[uncompyle](https://github.com/gstarnberger/uncompyle)

"'uncompyle' converts Python byte-code back into equivalent Python
source. It accepts byte-code from Python version 2.7 only"